# Modify existing xpath expression in Odoo

Tags: xpath, replace, odoo

I have to modify the xpath of Odoo module in my custom module. Consider below this code of website_sale module of V11 (For simplicity, i have reduced code):

```
<template id="recommended_products" inherit_id="website_sale.product" customize_show="True" name="Alternative Products">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='product_full_description']" position="after">
        <div class="container mt32" t-if="product.alternative_product_ids">
            <h3>Alternative Products:</h3>                                        
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

For example, I want to replace

1) position="after" to position="before"

OR

2) expr="//div[@id='product_full_description']"  to expr="//div[@id='product_small_description']"

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
<template id="recommended_products" inherit_id="website_sale.product" customize_show="True" name="Alternative Products">
    <!-- this will replace the existing place of the div -->
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='product_full_description']" position="replace">
    </xpath>
    <!-- this will be the new place of the div. Instead of after you use before -->
     <xpath expr="//div[@id='product_full_description']" position="before">
        <div class="container mt32" t-if="product.alternative_product_ids">
            <h3>Alternative Products:</h3>                                        
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I will explain a very rare(non-documented) and useful Odoo XML views inheritance to be able to replace the whole view without overriding the record view data.

For example if you wanna override(bad practice) the content of the view `website_sale.product`, you could do this(using the same record xml id of the other record)

```
<!-- Not Recommended for almost every case -->
<template id="website_sale.product" name="Product">
    ...
    <!-- Reorganize the original view as needed -->
    ...
</template>
```

This has the inconvenience of loosing the original code and it could fail when the module that introduce the changes get uninstalled because the changes will live on the original record view and lead to some errors.

The proposed way(rare and not documented) is using this kind of inheritance:

```
<template id="recommended_products_ext" inherit_id="website_sale.recommended_products">
    <xpath expr="." position="replace">
        <t name="Alternative Products" t-name="website_sale.recommended_products">
            ...
            <!-- Reorganize the original view as needed -->
            ...
        </t>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

This format allow to introduce original views override by extension, without manual modifiying the original code of the inherited view. In fact the format: `<t name"" t-name=""></t>` is the way Odoo store the qweb templates in the DB and I benefit from that to allow me to introduce the whole view override while playing nice with others inheritance of the same view.

Keep in mind that this is a tool that maybe needs help from module depends and view priority to be allowed to act as soon as possible to inject the changes before others views inheritance could use their turn.

I find this question a good place to share about this solution. But feel free to evaluate if apply for your case

*** Update ***
An example gist:

https://gist.github.com/aek/d8a3588e1f8c63f96be242f4d6d75b09

Comment: Thanks, Axel. But I am not getting how do I do that. Can you show by doing an example considering the above code and my requirement?

Comment: The idea is to copy the original view code into the `<t name"" t-name=""></t>` tags and reorganize it without making replace and insert of the same code from one position to the other, just to make it according to the needs. I don't wanna put change the code example in the answer with an specific example. But to be able to show you how to do it for your scenario let me give you this gist:
https://gist.github.com/aek/d8a3588e1f8c63f96be242f4d6d75b09

Comment: Thanks Alex. Sorry for late response. I will try and let you know.

Comment: I am getting below error when i try to replace position "after" to "before":
Element '<xpath expr="//p[@t-field='product.description_sale']">' cannot be located in parent view

If i directly update in original code then it works fine. Can you please help me what is going wrong? Sometimes i think odoo does not have proper way for template inheritance.

Comment: Sorry Ankit, I have tested this and you are correct. Seems that my rare view inheritance only works for base views(non inherited ones). I have to continue study this topic to find the complete solution, because it bring new ways to do stuffs